# Empirical Analysis of Merge and Insertion Sort - Difficulties

Tags: algorithm, sorting, testing, mergesort, insertion-sort

I'm trying to analyse the run time of my implementation of merge and insertion sort. I'm noticing a weird trend and I wasn't able to find anyone with the same problem through googling, but I'm probably using the wrong terms.

The number of times the sorting algorithms run, seem inversely related to the amount of time taken for the algorithm to complete. Sample shown below for insertion sort.

4213,2104,8195,9441,4823,925,980,964,911,491,470,482,481... (it settles on ~490ms)

And similar behaviour with merge sort, but merge settles on ~95ms.

I have no idea why this is happening, I'm generating a random array every time... even if it wasn't random shouldn't it just take exactly the same time every time (or close)? why does it converge on a smaller value?

Just looking for anyone who might know why this is happening because it seems really strange to me... I'm assuming it's something Java is doing behind the scenes maybe? Any suggestions/tips appreciated!

All the code I am running is posted below. With the test code shown first.

```
public static void tests(int noTests, int arraySize){
    //set up the running totals of the time taken by insertion and merge
    double insertSum = 0;
    double mergeSum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < noTests; i++){
        //generate an array of random integers
        Integer[] randInput = generateRandomArray(arraySize);
        Integer[] insertInput = Arrays.copyOf(randInput, randInput.length);
        Integer[] mergeInput = Arrays.copyOf(randInput, randInput.length);
        //start the clock for insertion
        final long insertionStart = System.nanoTime();
        //sort it 
        insertionSort(insertInput);
        //stop the clock for insertion
        final long insertionFinish = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken for insertion: " + (insertionFinish - insertionStart)/1000 + " ms");
        //add it to the running total 
        insertSum += (insertionFinish - insertionStart)/1000;

        //likewise for merge 
        final long mergeStart = System.nanoTime();
        mergeSort(mergeInput);
        final long mergeFinish = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken for merge: " + (mergeFinish - mergeStart)/1000 + " ms");
        mergeSum += (mergeFinish - mergeStart)/1000;
    }
    //Get the average by diving by the number of times it ran 
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Insert average: " + insertSum/noTests);
    System.out.println("Merge average: " + mergeSum/noTests);
}

//Generate an array of random Integers 
public static Integer[] generateRandomArray(int n){
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }
    return arr;
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] insertionSort(T[] a){
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
        int j = i-1;
        T key = a[i];

        while(j >= 0 && a[j].compareTo(key) > 0){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        a[j+1] = key;
    }
    return a;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] input){

    if(input.length<=1){
        return input;
    }

    int middle = Math.floorDiv(input.length, 2);

    Comparable a[] = new Comparable[middle];
    for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++){
        a[i] = input[i];
    }

    Comparable b[] = new Comparable[input.length - middle];
    for(int i = middle; i < input.length; i++){
        b[i-middle] = input[i];
    }

    mergeSort(a);
    mergeSort(b);
    merge(input, a, b);

    return input;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static void merge(Comparable[] input, Comparable[] a, Comparable[] b){

    int inputIndex = 0;
    int aIndex = 0;
    int bIndex = 0;

    while(aIndex < a.length && bIndex < b.length){

            if(aIndex < a.length & a[aIndex].compareTo(b[bIndex]) < 0){
                input[inputIndex] = a[aIndex];
                aIndex++;
            } else{
                input[inputIndex] = b[bIndex];
                bIndex++;
            }
            inputIndex++;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Time taken for insertion: 8060 ms
Time taken for merge: 1714 ms
Time taken for insertion: 11533 ms
Time taken for merge: 23418 ms
Time taken for insertion: 5674 ms
Time taken for merge: 326 ms
Time taken for insertion: 8235 ms
Time taken for merge: 459 ms
Time taken for insertion: 9737 ms
Time taken for merge: 333 ms
Time taken for insertion: 4756 ms
Time taken for merge: 374 ms
Time taken for insertion: 1088 ms
Time taken for merge: 493 ms
Time taken for insertion: 899 ms
Time taken for merge: 1147 ms
Time taken for insertion: 783 ms
Time taken for merge: 474 ms
Time taken for insertion: 653 ms
Time taken for merge: 252 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
Insert average: 5141.8
Merge average: 2899.0
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** Updated pass by reference error, insert and merge are now both sorting their own arrays. Problem persists. Updated example output, if given more terms insert eventually still converges on a much lower value than when it starts

Comment: I'm not sure of the overhead of Java when being run on repeated tests. `Other issues` -  It seems that mergesort is being run on an already sorted instance of randInput. Make a copy of randInput, so insertion sort works on the original, and merge sort works on the copy. The merge function is missing the code that copies the remainder of the "other" run when the end of a run is reached.

Comment: Should be fixed, weirdness persists.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `randInput` to insertion sort then pass this to merge sort.
In Java, Arrays are passed by **reference**. In `call by reference` if you change its array in a method, the changed array will be available to the calling array.

So `randInput` is sorted when pass to `mergesot`method.
See this:

```
//generate an array of random integers
Integer[] randInput = generateRandomArray(arraySize);
// randInput is random
insertionSort(randInput); 

// randInput is sorted
mergeSort(randInput);
```

Comment: Man! That's embarrassing. But even given that it doesn't explain why they converge. Insertion sort should be unaffected. 

- I did fix this reference issue in my code and the weirdness persists.